# Selector for pressed button

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is there any option, or special selector to change the style for a pressed button, what I mean by that..when a user clicks a button I want to change the style for that button? Is there any option to do that like: `:focus` or only with javascript click/focus event?

Comment: You should accept some answers, especially when, like below, they answer your questions. Otherwise, you probably won't get too many questions answered as time goes on…

Comment: I allways accept them, but you need to wait about 10 min before you can accept an answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `:active` pseudo-class...

```css
#btn { border: solid 5px red; padding: 5px; }
#btn:hover { border-color: green; }
#btn:active { border-color: blue; }
```

```html
<button id="btn" />
```

Note: if you are using both `:hover` and `:active` on a single element, the `:hover` definition must come first.